# Swift 3 code hides my UIImageView

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to create a circle UIImageView. Before swift 3 I had been using this code:

```
    profilePictureView.layer.cornerRadius = profilePictureView.frame.size.width / 2
    profilePictureView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    profilePictureView.clipsToBounds = true
```

It worked fine (created picture in circle). But now the code above hides my UIImageView and I do not know why.
Does anyone know why is it happening?

Edit:
profilePictureView is an @IBOutlet from my UserInterface.

Thank you.

Comment: In what method is your code (viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear etc.)? Most likely, you set it too early in the lifecycle.

Comment: In viewDidLoad() . Should I try putting it to another method?

Comment: Try to move it to viewDidAppear. Layout isn't finished until viewDidAppear is called. So most likely you don't have a valid frame size anyway.

Comment: Yeah that's it :) good point. Thanks @Codo

Comment: Just out of curosity: what's the value of `profilePictureView.frame.size.width` in `viewDidLoad`? Is it very large (like 1000) and therefore the rounded corners eats away the entire view area?

Comment: the frame was like (0.0 ,0.0, 1000 ,1000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until `viewDidAppear` is called, layout isn't finished and the frame size isn't valid. Most likely, your code is called too early in the life-cycle.

So move your code to `viewDidAppear` and you should be fine.

BTW: As far as I can tell, it's a iOS 10 issue (ant not a Swift 3 issue).